# Create a variable for a button from a string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, button

so I would like to create a button from a string. I know how to access a button by a string if it is already created but that isn't the case atm.

Like this: `Button "myButton" = new Button();`

But of course that does not work, is this possible to do?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what "create a button from a string" means? Are you trying to associate a string with a button in some way?

Comment: @E.Moffat I am sorry for the vague title, I would like to create the button name from a string. As I've shown in my example. Button "myButton" = new Button();

Comment: *" I know how to access a button by a string if it is already created"* how are you planning to do that? I think you'll find they are searching by the `Name` property of a button and don't care at all what the local variable name is. Example [ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.100).aspx) is searching the `Name` of a control, which is different than any local variable name

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is name a variable from a string... this has nothing to do with creating a button.

Comment: You can't create a code identifier `myButton` from a string that is determined later (after compilation), such as `"myButton"`. The best you can do is use an associative container like a Dictionary, or set the `Name` property on the `Button`.

Comment: Use a Dictionary maybe? Map "myButton" string to myButton object. You know variable names mean nothing to the compiler right?

Comment: @LibertyLocked But when I use a dictionary am I able to change the properties of the button? Like the position?

Comment: @J.Doe: Yes, of course. A button can be both added to a form and added to your dictionary. You can use the dictionary to quickly find buttons and you'll get a reference to the *same object* as the one you added to the form.

Comment: @MattBurland Thanks for your comment, These are really helpful but I have one last question: How can I place the button from the Dictionary?

Comment: Alternatively, you can set `myButton.Name` and use LINQ to search for it in your form's `Controls`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are using [ControlCollection.Find](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find(v=vs.100).aspx) to find your controls by a string, then note the MSDN entry:

> Searches for controls by their Name property and builds an array of all the controls that match.

It doesn't care what (if any) variable name the button was assigned to (nor can it know or use it in any useful way), it cares only about the `Name` property of your button. So you could do something like this:

```
var IDontCareWhatThisIsCalled = new Button()
{
    Name = "myButton"
};
someForm.Controls.Add(IDontCareWhatThisIsCalled);
```

And then:

```
var thatButton = someForm.Controls.Find("myButton");
```

However, if you have a bunch of buttons that you need to be able to look up by name, then the best option is probably to put them in a `Dictionary<string,Button>`:

```
Dictionary<string,Button> buttonDictionary = new Dictionary<string,Button>();
// ....
var b = new Button();
buttonDictionary["myButton"] = b;
someForm.Controls.Add(b);
// ...
// To retrieve later:
var thatButton = buttonDictionary["myButton"];   // Note if the key doesn't exist, it will
                                                 // throw an exception - so check first
```